# How to alter PHP replace function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'myCatNoBrk', 10, 1);

function myCatNoBrk($OrgCat) {
       $CatNoBrk = preg_replace('/<br \/>/',',',$OrgCat);
       return $CatNoBrk;
    }
```

Hello, this is part of a wordpress function that would replace html breaks with commas. How could I alter this to also remove  and add 'x' around each element?

in other words:
The output code is something like

```
<a href="xxx">cat1</a><br>
<a href="xxx2">cat2</a><br>
and so on
```

I'd like to change this to show only ('cat1','cat2') for an array definition

example output:

```
<?php $grades_array = array('a+','a','a-','b+','b','b-','c+');?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add 'x' around each element"? What element do you mean, and if we're removing it, how can we add 'x' around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but here's a replacement function that lets you specify what you are putting in place of the break tags (<br />)

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'myCatNoBrk', 10, 1);

function myCatNoBrk($OrgCat,$replacement = ',') {
       $CatNoBrk = preg_replace('/<br \/>/',$replacement,$OrgCat);
       return $CatNoBrk;
    }
```

UPDATE: 
try this

```
add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'myCatNoBrk', 10, 1);

  function myCatNoBrk($OrgCat,) {

       preg_match_all(' /(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)/',$OrgCat,$CatNoBrk,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
       return '(\''.implode('\',\'',$CatNoBrk).'\')';
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, sadly it has a parse error

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE"

Comment: OK, so it looks like you want to remove the whole <a href... > as well. Is that right?

Comment: for something like this <?php $grades_array = array('a+','a','a-','b+','b','b-','c+');?>

Comment: thanks so much for your time! but no cigar. still gets the same parsing error as in the first comment.

Comment: ps, this is the site the theming is working from http://www.walkernews.net/2010/01/09/display-wordpress-categories-in-one-comma-separated-line/

Comment: So, the original function is given a string of several links to categories separated by break tags, and returns those same links separated by commas, right?

Comment: OK, based on what you've said here, I am not really sure this is the best place to try and pull an array of categories from. It's highly likely the array you're looking for is generated previously and then used to generate the link tags. If you can EITHER use that array, OR use the function that generates that array, you'll be better off.

Comment: thanks, I'd imagine that would be in this huge file: category_template.php http://codeviewer.org/view/code:132d

Comment: the function wp_list_categories() on line 453 is the one that generates the list of links. On line 489 is a call to the function you REALLY want - get_categories(). I am not sure where this is defined.

Comment: ahh, yes, in here http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/category.php

i can't figure out what code it generates though. Is it in the array() form?

Comment: Yes it does return an array, however the array will contain more than just the names of the categories - it looks like it contains additional information. (PS: Sorry about the delay, I had to go offline)